# Creating dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/367ms/1/

Please take a look at my code. So what I want to achieve - the blue border, when hovered is 10 px under the text. In additional, as you can see when you hover it opens submenu, but when I want to go down to submenu, it automatically closes, since there is no more hover on li element. I can fix that by adding height: 50px; but that also makes the blue border, go under the submenu and I have arrows in right center position, and they are ugly when hovered. Could you please help me fixing these two issues? With allowing to move mouse on submenu and the blue border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a space between *ul* and *li* that breaks the *:hover*, if you remove top and bottom margins and `top: 51px;` you'll access to the drop down menu.

Use paddings instead of margins thus mouse don't get out of element.

It may be easier to use JavaScript to do that but not impossible with CSS.

**EDIT**
It seems to blink only between the blue line and th sub *li*, remember this rule:

```
#top-menu-wrapper #menu ul li:hover
```

It has effect on all descendant *li*, you may need to rewrite it as 2 rules, to get the direct children the first would be:

```
#top-menu-wrapper #menu > ul > li:hover
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't fix the first issue with border, as you can see the border now is under the submenu. And the submenu must start 20px below the text, so the blue border is between the submenu and li text.

Comment: Adding height: 40px; to li:hover element and 50px; to li element almost fixes the problem, now it blinks if i set mouse over the border.

Comment: It may blink when 2 (or more) elements are hovered.

Comment: Well, there aren't 2 elements hovered, since it's only one li element with hover effect.

Comment: When your *li* is hovered, does the dropdown menu cover it ?  Could you update your fiddle ? Could you synthetize your question and give it a readable layout ?

Comment: Updated - http://jsfiddle.net/367ms/8/ . As you can see, like this I want to locate everything, but when i hover on the a element, and then go down till the border, and move mouse over the border, it somehow blinks.

Answer (score 0):

you should use jquery to do the animation, when user hover to the blue one, you check whether the sub-menu is opened yet, if not open it, if it is currently open, do nothing.

```
$(...).mouseover(function(){});
```

Comment: Can you try editing my example? I know how to add show/hide functions, but well, won't it have the same problem as it currently has?

Comment: There is no reason to use JavaScript for simple dropdown functionality. Look at sinsedrix answer that brings you in the right direction.